# Get quaternion from gps data

Tags: math, gps, quaternions

Is there possible way of obtaining the quaternion from GPS data including latitude, longitude, altitude, and vehicle heading(yaw angle) or Any c++ libs to deal with this task.

Comment: If you read from GPS module directly (normally over serial link) they're just lines of comma separated values. For details try to have a search for "NMEA data".

Comment: A single quaternion cannot represent a position or translation. So, no, there is no way. If you restrict yourself to the rotation, you need to be more specific (what rotation exactly do you want to represent in what coordinate system)?

Comment: @KenCheung Thanks, that is a new thing I haven't go in to detail before, by the way I use gps module come with pixhawk which installed firmware already calculating lat, lon, alt, and heading(yaw).

Comment: @NicoSchertler How about if I want the rotation represent in either NED or camera coordinate. How can i obtain the rotation matrix? could you please guide me more.

Comment: @Rasp: you should check NMEA data, most modules can gives you data in such format. Yes, the data is calculated by hardware/firmware/software. NMEA is just a standard format to give you all the data in a standardized form.